# What does [class] mean here, what does it do?

Tags: css

```
.modal-popup .modal-slide {
    .modal-inner-wrap[class] {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
    }
}
```

If I remove the [class] the styling doesn't apply, I'm guessing it applies the style to all the classes of the children elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Q: What does `[class]` mean here?

**A:** `.modal-inner-wrap[class]` will select all elements that have a CSS class `modal-inner-wrap` **and that also** have a `class` attribute (which they obviously have if they match the first condition).

### Q: [...] and what does it do?

**A:** The only reason I can think of why one would add `[class]` is to raise [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). This assumption is also supported by your observation

> If I remove the [class] the styling doesn't apply